# How to serve a summons to payment hearing to a debtor?

Tags: canada, small-claims-court, british-columbia, service

Must the creditor personally serve the debtor face to face? Is it OK to put the document inside a regular envelope and must the envelope be labelled with anything? Must the creditor say anything to the debtor when serving the document? I understand if the debtor refuses to hold the document you can just drop it in front of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rule 16 of the Small Claims Rules](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/261_93_04#rule18subrule14) states this...

> **Written proof of service**
>
> [...]
>
> 14(e) for personal service of a summons to a payment hearing, **an
> affidavit of service.**

And *Form 12 Summons to a Payment Hearing* at Schedule B includes the [Affidavit of Service](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/loo70/loo70/261_93_06#form12-6) which appears to give just two options...

> Leaving a copy of it with him or her.
>
> As directed by the court by...

The rules do not mention, and therefore do not seem to require, anything other than "Leaving a copy" with the debtor, but common sense should prevail to avoid the hearing being unnecessarily diverted away from the points at issue.

**Edited To Add**

> *Rule 15 Oral proof of service*
>
> Instead of requiring proof of service under subrule (14), a judge or
> registrar may allow a person to prove by sworn oral evidence that the
> person has personally served a document.